# When I click on first pie on the page, the second appears, but then I cannot do anything with the first

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

Like stated in the title, I got the problem when I click on some slice of pie. I call function, which displays hidden div with the second pie. It appears correctly, but then I cannot click on that first pie and even tooltips are not displaying. And the second pie is all black, but that is the lesser problem, I think... Thanks for advices in advance!

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? Also, check FAQ: http://docs.highcharts.com/#faq$jquery-ui-tab

Comment: Yes, sorry, here´s the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4scfH/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your fiddle with my changes: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r36qe/).

To fix hover and click events on first chart, I've deleted `position: relative` of second container.

To fix issue with black colors, I moved colors declaration into `Highcharts.Chart({...})`. Otherwise, you'll re-rewrite Highchart colors while creating the second chart.